# watchos2 - Can I implement multiple storyboards?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, watchkit

In iOS, I instantiate smaller (sub-) storyboards using something like this:

```
- (IBAction)showTrains:(id)sender {
    UIStoryboard *trainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Train" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *mainTrainViewController = [trainStoryboard instantiateInitialViewController];
    mainTrainViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentViewController:mainTrainViewController animated:YES completion: nil];

}
```

I understand in Xcode 7+, we can subdivide watches storyboards. Has anyone done this, and how, please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible at the moment since a storyboard (`UIStoryboard`) is a part of UIKit framework you [can see](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKit_Framework/index.html) that it's not available in UIKit for 3rd party developers on Watch for now.

[There is](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WatchKit_framework/) nothing related to storyboards in WatchKit framework as well.

Comment: Thanks @Dmitry. I've read the doc links you sent (+1), and I think you are correct.